# Windows Phone 7 and Javascript Accelerometers

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to gain access to the Accelerometer data via Javascript on a Windows Phone 7?

The iPhone has this demo example (that works lovely in Safari mobile):
http://hakim.se/experiments/css/holobox/

The section of iPhone Javascript is as follows:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android)/i)) {
        addEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange, false);
        addEventListener("devicemotion", onMotionChange, false);
    }
```

I just wondered whether you can access the data on WP7 as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Just as well it isn't my code, I wondered whether the same sort of thing was possible on WP7...?

Comment: I'm not sure of the support for these events on IEM (hence no answer), just wanted to point out that this method of detection should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible. Even in Mango.

Comment: You can do it natively and pass it to a hosted webbrowser control though (e.g. at https://github.com/mrlacey/phonegap-wp7/tree/master/rtm). That's as close as it gets for now. Myabe IE10 mobile will add this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some cross-platform javascript libraries that allow you to access the Accelerometer and other services on some phones. You have [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) for instance.

As far as I know, none of these allow you to access the services on the WP7 yet.

In the upcoming Mango update for WP7 html/javascript apps are supposed to be supported, so you may want to download the beta SDK and check there. I don't know whether the beta supports this information but it should be easy to check.

Check out this project on Codeplex for more information: http://htmlappwp7.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry, is this possible? Your first sentence says "...that allow you to access the Accelerometer..." and your second sentence says "...none of these allow you to access..."

Comment: It works on other mobile platforms than WP7. iOS and Android and others are supported.